# Highlight direct code change (diff, vimdiff, meld)

Tags: linux, bash, compare, diff

In a `diff` the changes are marked in red and green per line.
Is there a way to mark the text changes within the line?

That would be a comparison with diff:

```bash
diff \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored changed-bold-colored same-colored\nsame") \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored CHANGED-BOLD-COLORED same-colored\nsame")
```

I would like an output like `vimdiff` or `meld`.
Only very simple and output directly in the terminal.

Like this output for example:

```bash
red='\033[0;31m'; redDark='\033[7;31m'; green='\033[0;32m'; greenDark='\033[7;32m'; noColor='\033[0m'
printf "${red}same-colored ${redDark}changed-bold-colored${red} same-colored${noColor}\n"
printf "${green}same-colored ${greenDark}changed-bold-colored${green} same-colored${noColor}\n"
```

[image]

Is this possible without much effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't produce the output you asked for but it's output may give you the information you need:

```
git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2
```

You do not need to be in a git repo to use that command.

Here's the same command run 3 times with the output displayed in different ways to make sure it can be seen here:

[image]

```
$ git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored changed-bold-colored same-colored\nsame") \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored CHANGED-BOLD-COLORED same-colored\nsame")
diff --git a/dev/fd/63 b/dev/fd/62
--- a/dev/fd/63
+++ b/dev/fd/62
@@ -2 +2 @@ same
same-colored changedCHANGED-boldBOLD-coloredCOLORED same-colored
$
```

```
$ git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored changed-bold-colored same-colored\nsame") \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored CHANGED-BOLD-COLORED same-colored\nsame") \
        | cat -A
^[[1mdiff --git a/dev/fd/63 b/dev/fd/62^[[m$
^[[1m--- a/dev/fd/63^[[m$
^[[1m+++ b/dev/fd/62^[[m$
^[[36m@@ -2 +2 @@^[[m ^[[msame^[[m$
same-colored ^[[31mchanged^[[m^[[32mCHANGED^[[m-^[[31mbold^[[m^[[32mBOLD^[[m-^[[31mcolored^[[m^[[32mCOLORED^[[m same-colored$
$
```

If you have the kind of problems using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) with `git diff` as described by the OP in comments below or like this:

```
$ git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored changed-bold-colored same-colored\nsame") \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored CHANGED-BOLD-COLORED same-colored\nsame" )
error: Could not access '/proc/2063/fd/63'
```

then you could write a command like this to ensure that `git diff` always gets regular files to operate on:

```
$ cat $HOME/bin/colordiff
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmpDir=$(mktemp -d)  || exit 1
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpDir"; exit' EXIT

tmpFiles=()
for file; do
    tmpFile="$tmpDir/$file"
    mkdir -p -- "$tmpDir/${file%/*}"
    cp -- "$file" "$tmpFile"
    tmpFiles+=( "$tmpFile" )
done

git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. "${tmpFiles[@]}"
```

which you'd then call as:

```
$ colordiff \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored changed-bold-colored same-colored\nsame") \
    <(printf "same\nsame-colored CHANGED-BOLD-COLORED same-colored\nsame")
diff --git a/C:/Some/Path/Temp/tmp.E5Pv4qtlnH/dev/fd/63 b/C:/Some/Path/Temp/tmp.E5Pv4qtlnH/dev/fd/62
index 078906c..275fedd 100644
--- a/C:/Some/Path/Temp/tmp.E5Pv4qtlnH/dev/fd/63
+++ b/C:/Some/Path/Temp/tmp.E5Pv4qtlnH/dev/fd/62
@@ -2 +2 @@ same
same-colored changedCHANGED-boldBOLD-coloredCOLORED same-colored
```

Comment: Something strange is happening to me.
When I use the bash pipes "<(...)", instead of the contents of the file, only this is displayed each file: "pipe:[1937222]".
If I do this with two real files, it works.
`git --version`: git version 2.34.1

Comment: Maybe whatever you have inside `<(...)` is invalid? Or maybe your bash version doesn't create a temp file for the `<(...)` output and then `git diff` chokes? Idk. If using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), `<(...)` doesn't work for you for this then just don't use it, use temp files.

Comment: `echo ${BASH_VERSION}`: 5.1.16(1)-release.
`echo ${ZSH_VERSION}`: 5.8.1.
`echo <(echo 'x')`: /dev/fd/63.
Good question, but yes, if in doubt, two temporary files will also work. Or something like:
`printf "text1" | git diff -U0 --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. - file2`

Comment: I edited my answer to show a script you could use to work around the problem.

Comment: Note, in Ubuntu there is another package with the same name: `apt-cache search 'colordiff'`.
Since there are only two files, how about this change:
https://cryptpad.fr/code/#/2/code/view/pWnVlnJRNTqvP8W6QucIZpwlSWMk91bcZcixEUTuuJU/ .

Would then also create hidden files and also compares strings: `./script <(echo 'abc') 'axc'`.

However, I don't know whether checking file or string is reasonable.

Comment: You don't have to use that name, pick one that works for you. If you have a script you'd like reviewed, submit it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.